# Как лучше объединить 2 облака?

Tags: backend, миграция, облако

Имеется 2 облака и 2 разных домена. Хотим перенести все в одно облако. Подскажите, как лучше это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Особенности:**

1. На обоих облаках одинаковый код, отличается только клиентская база.
2. Нельзя прерывать обслуживание на долгий срок.
3. Нужно чтобы клиенты остались на разных доменах.

С технической точки зрения понятно как это сделать, тут вопросов нет. Вопрос больше в подходе. Как лучше перенести клиентов, с минимальными жертвами для них?

Клиенты большие, имеют свою инфраструктуру. Поэтому вероятно будем переносить по очереди и отдельно согласовывать с каждым.

**Идеи которые имеются на данный момент:**

1. Сделать 3й домен, который останется навсегда, переносить всех туда.
2. Сделать proxy-pass в apigw и определять клиентов.
3. Сделать 3й домен 3го уровня и два раза перенести клиентов, сначала на него, а потом на нужный (ужасно с точки зрения бизнеса).

#### Подскажите пожалуйста какие еще есть варианты? Возможно у кого-то был подобный опыт?